# Database mirroring a live database

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, database-mirroring

I've been reading about database mirroring on SQL Server 2008 R2 / 2012 and I have a question: does it matter if the database being mirrored is live? Do I have to do anything special or different if my database is live?

**EDIT-1:**

- I have a (one) database on premises that's our production database. A few hundreds transactions happens per second, and 99.999% are read operations. Our plan is to mirror this database (single database) to SQL Azure (IaaS) as a "backup" structure, if the on premises environment crash for any reason, we just point to the cloud.
- I would like a zero loss, but I settle for a 5 seconds loss
- Latency wont be a problem... slow running is better than no running...
- I have just one node and one database

Comment: Would you be able to clarify what you mean by live?

Comment: @ChrisH edited! check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest thing to consider if you run in either high-performance or high-safety mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx

Basically, in high-performance the transaction is committed locally and hopefully on the remote side.  The mirrored server asynchronously applies the transactions and data loss may be a factor.  The upside is not having latency in the local server and you only need two machines.

In high-safety, the transaction is witnessed by a third server and has to be committed on both sides.  This creates latency which would not be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things to consider when using mirroring with a live DB.

- How many nodes do you have?
- You need to know the the approximate load you expect.
- Consider the appropriate transaction safety level. The transaction safety level determines whether the changes on the principal database are applied to the mirror database synchronously or asynchronously.
- Another is your network setup. Are your nodes on LAN, WAN, etc.
- How many DBs are you mirroring.  Based on this answer, your choices for the above might differ.
- What sort of Disaster recovery do you need should the worst happen?

Comment: Excellent updates.  I was just giving the initial things to consider.  Based on your updated question, I'd take a look at the cases in this post and adjust accordingly: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917681.aspx

Comment: I have several other white papers on the subject, I'll post if the above doesn't satisfy your need.

Comment: Was this helpful to you at all?